# Android Studio Error Emulator: dsound: warning: Voice is not capturing api 28 emulator doesnt work

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am facing this current error in the

> Emulator: dsound: warning: Voice is not capturing.

I have tried all other solutions such as enabling the microphone settings via windows it seems to be not working. While the emulator loads up but does not load the app. The emulator seems to be working perfectly fine for another app on my android studio. Can someone help me with this error please [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSWWl.png)

Thanks

Comment: I have tried all the solutions within the Android Emulator Audio Input Failed post  but none  of them seem to work and there error he is facing is different to my error.

Comment: actually, a warning is not an error... and unless you add the stack-trace of the crash, I don't really believe that this is the reason why your app is not working - simply because you claim another app would be working, which means that the emulator _is_ generally working.

Comment: im getting errors like this in the stack trace                                   
E/droid.deskcloc: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent. i have inlcuded a image above of the stack trace if you can see it

Comment: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-9120 ...seems to be a bug.

Comment: is this a bug within the app created as it seems to be only affecting this app from only not working in the emulator and the connected device.

Comment: the other app might not use Appcelerator; disabling it should make it work.

Comment: how could i disable the Appcelerator within Android studio.

Comment: when looking at the question and the basically non-existent stack-trace; you probably can wait long for any reliable answer. besides: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company (bugs in commercial products also count towards towards customer support).